# UITabBarController Cropped

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `button` in a `viewcontroller` that loads a `motherViewController`. This seems to be working correctly but for some reason the newly introduced `view` is so tall that the content at the bottom of are cropped.

```
- (IBAction)LoginButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
        FirstViewController *FirstView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];
        SecondViewController *SecondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Second"];
        ThirdViewController *ThirdView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Third"];
        FourthViewController *FourthView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fourth"];
        FifthViewController *FifthView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Fifth"];

        FirstView.Username = self.UsernameBox.text;

        UINavigationController *FirstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [FirstNavController pushViewController:FirstView animated:NO];

        UINavigationController *SecondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [SecondNavController pushViewController:SecondView animated:NO];

        UINavigationController *ThirdNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [ThirdNavController pushViewController:ThirdView animated:NO];

        UINavigationController *FourthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [FourthNavController pushViewController:FourthView animated:NO];

        UINavigationController *FifthNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
        [FifthNavController pushViewController:FifthView animated:NO];


        tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];    
        tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:FirstView, SecondView, ThirdView, FourthView, FifthView, nil];
        [self.view addSubview:tabBar.view];

}
```

[image: View controller]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't whether i'm right or not. But here's the answer, you are trying to add `UIViewController (UITabbarController)` to your `ViewController`. So you need to position it in your `view`, for example

```
tabbar.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
```

But only thing i don't know its how it's perfectly positioned, when we are adding to `window`. Try your code by setting `frame` for your `tabbarcontroller`.

Comment: Worked like a charm but is there any other way to achieve this goal without hard coding the positions and dimensions?

Comment: try `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);`

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
 tabBar.tabBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: tried it but it did not make any difference. Thank you for your suggestion though.